# How do I check if variable defined in an Ansible playbook contains a string value?

Tags: ansible

I want to validate that the input values passed to the variables as extra_args.

I want to run a pre-task that passes if the variable contains a string value, else fails if it contains anything else.

The values are passed to them as extra_args when executing the playbook.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to run a pre-task that passes if the variable contains a string value, else fails if it contains anything else.

This task fails if the `variable` is not a string object:

```
- fail:
  when: variable is not string
```

But be aware that all values passed as extra-vars will be strings, because that's what they are -- anything you type on your keyboard is a valid string. As there is no type declaration, even if a variable contains a numerical value, it will be stored in a string object.

It is different to variable values defined in YAML which undergo type autodetection performed by YAML parser. For example if you type `myvar: true` in YAML, it will be considered Boolean object `true`, but if you pass the same value with `--extra-vars "myvar:true"`, it will be a string object `true`.

You need to specify another condition.

Comment: Great. Worked out fine.
Also, I am passing the extra_args by loading from a json file which takes the numeric value as numeric itself rather than a string object.

Comment: Just to be sure check if it does not fail every time.

Comment: Checked. Doesn't fail everytime.

Comment: The above works fine for a string input. Could I do the same to check if a variable is not a boolean, dictionary or object?

Answer (score 0):

Here are few filters and tests in ansible you may find it useful

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_tests.html

for validation you might use it as follows:

```
tasks: 
   - fail: msg="Variable '{{ item }}' is not a string" 
     when: string | search("^[a-zA-Z]*$")
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use the 'assert' module for such cases like this.

```
- name: Test if the type of 'variable' is string
  assert:
    that:
      - variable is defined
      - variable is string
    fail_msg: |
      variable: {{ variable | d() | to_nice_json }}
```

seealso: type check examples: https://github.com/ssato/ansible-role-assertive-programming-examples/blob/master/tasks/pre_type_checks.yml

BTW, if you want to define variables with types you want using --extra-vars (-e) option, you need to prepare yaml files define these variables and let them loaded using '@' such like '-e @/path/to/the/yaml_file'.